# Where should I put uploaded files in Rails 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, file-upload, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline, carrierwave

I am using CarrierWave to do Image upload and I am not sure where I should put these files and how I can access these files in my view. I am mainly having this problem in production where the images appear to be missing. It works just fine in development.

Where should I put these files so that it is accessible through URL and from the view? I have tried putting it in 'public/uploads/picture/1/image.jpg' but I still cannot access the image from the url

```
/assets/uploads/picture....
```

What is the right way to do this?

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  include CarrierWave::RMagick
  #include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :file
  # storage :fog

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
```

[EDIT]

So I did 'ls -al' inside the folder that contains all the images and this is what I got

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root     root  4096 Feb 20 23:07 . drwxr-xr-x 4 deployer root  4096 Feb 20 23:07 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root  2313 Feb 20 23:07 doraemon.gif
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root 13367 Feb 20 23:07 profile_doraemon.gif
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root  2313 Feb 20 23:07 shoutout_thumb_doraemon.gif
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root  9201 Feb 20 23:07 thumb_doraemon.gif
```

It looks like when the file is uploaded. The files are owned by root. The folders and subfolder that contain it are also owned by root. For example, this is the folder that contains the files above.

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root     root 4096 Feb 20 23:07 7
```

Also, this is the path the the view/HTML is trying to access

```
<img alt="Thumb_doraemon" class="" data-id="7" src="/uploads/picture/image/7/thumb_doraemon.gif">
```

And in the server, the file is located in

```
public/uploads/picture/images/7/thumb_doraemon.gif
```

Comment: have you tried /public/image.jpg

Comment: production may not have permissions to upload to that dir, you may have to check that directory. Also, sometimes the assets folder needs to be pre-compiled, and blocks access to files that aren't precompiled (like the file you just uploaded). Check the file exists in the file system, and check the logs on production. If your using heroku then you have to use s3

Comment: So I just confirmed that the image is actually uploaded to in the right folder. Could this be a permission on that folder???

Comment: If the image is there, then its being stored ok. Check you have read access from the production user

Comment: saving as root is usually a bad idea...